# Generate a data frame with years as columns and conditional values in R

Tags: r

This is the kind of problem that I could easily solve for one observation and do it on excel, but I am not being able to replicate it in R.
I have a dataset that has information on cars gas expenditure by team. Each time can have one or more cars in circulation. Some of those cars will stop using gas (stop year) , but other new cars will start using gas (start year)

Team   Gas.Consumption   StopUsing        StartUsing
A           45000           2025            1999
A           50444           2035            1998
A           45666            NA             1999
A           45000            NA             2024
B           45000           2043            1997
B           56777            NA             2030
B           87666            NA            2033

I need to have a dataframe or time-series that gives me the total yearly consumption from today (2022) to 2100.
The new dataframe would have to sum all the cars in use from 2022 on, consider when these cars stop being used (and not sum their consumption anymore), and add the cars that start being used (and their consumptions). All of this information grouped by team.

In the end should be something like:
2022  2023  2024 .... 2100
A (yearly consumption 22)... (yearly consumption 2100)
B (yearly consumption 22)... (yearly consumption 2100)

I tried a for loop but I am not being able to code it properly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I believe this is what you are looking for.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
  ~Team, ~Gas.Consumption, ~StopUsing, ~StartUsing,
  "A", 45000, 2025, 1999,
  "A", 50444, 2035, 1998,
  "A", 45666, NA, 1999,
  "A", 45000, NA, 2024,
  "B", 45000, 2043, 1997,
  "B", 56777, NA, 2030,
  "B", 87666, NA, 2033
) %>%
  mutate(StopUsing=if_else(is.na(StopUsing), 2100, StopUsing),
         TimeSeries=map2(StartUsing, StopUsing, ~ .x:.y)) %>%
  unnest(cols=TimeSeries) %>% filter(TimeSeries>=2022) %>% group_by(Team, TimeSeries) %>%
  summarize(Gas.Consumption=sum(Gas.Consumption), .groups="drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=TimeSeries, values_from=Gas.Consumption)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 80
#>   Team  `2022` `2023` `2024` `2025` `2026` `2027` `2028` `2029` `2030` `2031`
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 A     141110 141110 186110 186110 141110 141110 141110 141110 141110 141110
#> 2 B      45000  45000  45000  45000  45000  45000  45000  45000 101777 101777
#> # … with 69 more variables: 2032 <dbl>, 2033 <dbl>, 2034 <dbl>, 2035 <dbl>,
#> #   2036 <dbl>, 2037 <dbl>, 2038 <dbl>, 2039 <dbl>, 2040 <dbl>, 2041 <dbl>,
#> #   2042 <dbl>, 2043 <dbl>, 2044 <dbl>, 2045 <dbl>, 2046 <dbl>, 2047 <dbl>,
#> #   2048 <dbl>, 2049 <dbl>, 2050 <dbl>, 2051 <dbl>, 2052 <dbl>, 2053 <dbl>,
#> #   2054 <dbl>, 2055 <dbl>, 2056 <dbl>, 2057 <dbl>, 2058 <dbl>, 2059 <dbl>,
#> #   2060 <dbl>, 2061 <dbl>, 2062 <dbl>, 2063 <dbl>, 2064 <dbl>, 2065 <dbl>,
#> #   2066 <dbl>, 2067 <dbl>, 2068 <dbl>, 2069 <dbl>, 2070 <dbl>, 2071 <dbl>,
#> #   2072 <dbl>, 2073 <dbl>, 2074 <dbl>, 2075 <dbl>, 2076 <dbl>, 2077 <dbl>,
#> #   2078 <dbl>, 2079 <dbl>, 2080 <dbl>, 2081 <dbl>, 2082 <dbl>, 2083 <dbl>,
#> #   2084 <dbl>, 2085 <dbl>, 2086 <dbl>, 2087 <dbl>, 2088 <dbl>, 2089 <dbl>,
#> #   2090 <dbl>, 2091 <dbl>, 2092 <dbl>, 2093 <dbl>, 2094 <dbl>, 2095 <dbl>,
#> #   2096 <dbl>, 2097 <dbl>, 2098 <dbl>, 2099 <dbl>, 2100 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>